# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') when display image in vue 3

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, vuejs3

I am new to vue js but when i try to display image by id on page there is an error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (read 'data')

**EventDetail.vue**

```
<img :src="require(`../../../e-vents api/public${event.cover.data.attributes.formats.medium.url}`)" alt="#"/>

data() {
        return {
            event: "",
        };
    },

mounted() {
        fetch(`http://localhost:1337/api/events/${this.id}?populate=*`)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => (this.event = data.data.attributes))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
},
```

I managed to display other data by `{{ event.title }}` but this one is not showing

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM3XG.jpg)

**Json Data**

```
{
"data": {
    "id": 2,
    "attributes": {
        "title": "Concert",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus blandit consequat diam, quis tristique mi luctus tincidunt..",
        "date": "2022-04-02T12:00:00.000Z",
        "duration": 4,
        "price": "Rp. 500.000",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-23T15:01:33.339Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-03-26T15:40:29.023Z",
        "publishedAt": "2022-03-23T15:01:34.908Z",
        "location": "Jl. Pintu Satu Senayan, Gelora, Kecamatan Tanah Abang, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 10270",
        "maps": "https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3966.3419031479493!2d106.79960821378528!3d-6.218564762636128!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x2e69f14d30079f01%3A0x2e74f2341fff266d!2sStadion%20Utama%20Gelora%20Bung%20Karno!5e0!3m2!1sid!2sid!4v1648308601225!5m2!1sid!2sid",
        "cover": {
            "data": {
                "id": 1,
                "attributes": {
                    "name": "concert.jpg",
                    "alternativeText": "concert",
                    "caption": "concert.jpg",
                    "width": 1920,
                    "height": 1280,
                    "formats": {
                        "thumbnail": {
                            "name": "thumbnail_concert.jpg",
                            "hash": "thumbnail_concert_a354ef139e",
                            "ext": ".jpg",
                            "mime": "image/jpeg",
                            "path": null,
                            "width": 234,
                            "height": 156,
                            "size": 5.15,
                            "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_concert_a354ef139e.jpg"
                        },
                        "large": {
                            "name": "large_concert.jpg",
                            "hash": "large_concert_a354ef139e",
                            "ext": ".jpg",
                            "mime": "image/jpeg",
                            "path": null,
                            "width": 1000,
                            "height": 667,
                            "size": 68.26,
                            "url": "/uploads/large_concert_a354ef139e.jpg"
                        },
                        "medium": {
                            "name": "medium_concert.jpg",
                            "hash": "medium_concert_a354ef139e",
                            "ext": ".jpg",
                            "mime": "image/jpeg",
                            "path": null,
                            "width": 750,
                            "height": 500,
                            "size": 37.81,
                            "url": "/uploads/medium_concert_a354ef139e.jpg"
                        },
                        "small": {
                            "name": "small_concert.jpg",
                            "hash": "small_concert_a354ef139e",
                            "ext": ".jpg",
                            "mime": "image/jpeg",
                            "path": null,
                            "width": 500,
                            "height": 333,
                            "size": 17.85,
                            "url": "/uploads/small_concert_a354ef139e.jpg"
                        }
                    },
                    "hash": "concert_a354ef139e",
                    "ext": ".jpg",
                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                    "size": 281.82,
                    "url": "/uploads/concert_a354ef139e.jpg",
                    "previewUrl": null,
                    "provider": "local",
                    "provider_metadata": null,
                    "createdAt": "2022-03-25T08:53:49.295Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-03-25T08:53:49.295Z"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

[when console.log looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB7mj.jpg)

Comment: looks like it should be `data.cover.data.attributes` - on your console.log picture

Comment: By using data.cover.data.attributes when retrieving data I try to display it with :src="require(`../../../e-vents-api/public${event.formats.large.url} `)" but still there is an error